# Excel Solver - Reducing an If

Tags: excel, solver

I would like to reduce an `IF` statement so that I can use the Simplex LP method but I do not know who to go about doing this.

The expresion is below with `D14` & `E14` being the variable cells

`=IF(SUM(D14:E14)=0, 0, C14 - SUM(D14:E14))`

Comment: The `IF` expression equivalent to `SUM(D14:E14)`. If the sum is 0, it returns 0. If the sum is unequal 0, it returns the sum. So, it always returns the sum.

Comment: Sorry, it should have read  =IF(SUM(D14:E14)=0,0, C14-SUM(D14:E14))

Comment: What is the maximum value that `C14-SUM(D14:E14))` can have?

Answer (score 0):

The following expression could work for you:

```
=(SUM(D14:E14)<>0)*(C14-SUM(D14:E14))
```

Term `(SUM(D14:E14)<>0)` evaluates to `1`, if the sum is not zero. Otherwise, it evaluates to `0`.

**Note** that comparisons to zero might be disturbed by rounding errors, if the summands are non-integer values.

Comment: Hi Alex, unfortunately this approach reports that linearity conditions are not met to use the Simplex LP

Comment: Understood. The "L" in LP stand for Linear. A system of truly linear equations and inequalities is required to define an LP problem.

Comment: I have read about binary constraints to help remove the If statements

Comment: You might be better off using the Evolutionary solver. It can cope with non-linear constraints and merit/cost functions.